# Why this limit of function is resolved that way?

Tags: limits, functions, limits-without-lhopital

I have following function limit to find:
$$
\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\sqrt{2+\sin(6x)}-\sqrt{2-\sin(6x)}}{\tan(2x)}
$$
and the result with all steps is as following(excuse the image):
[image]

I don't understand the step where $2\sin(6x)\cos(2x)$ and $\sin(2x)$ becomes $2\frac{\sin(6x)}{x}$ and $\frac{\sin(2x)}{x}$.
What I am missing?

Comment: If you divide numerator and denominator by $x$, nothing will change.

Comment: @AbdallahHammam But then why $cos(2x)$ is not divided by $x$?

Comment: Because $\frac a x \cdot b = \frac {a\cdot b} x$.

Comment: @KarolisJuodelė I'm so stupid. Thank you for help